# Install ansible application to docker container

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile

I have an application which can be installed with ansible. No I want to create docker image that includes installed application.

My idea is to up docker container from some base image, after that start installation from external machine, to this docker container. After that create image from this container.

I am just starting with dockers, could you please advise if it is good idea and how can I do it?

Comment: You can add ```RUN ansible-playbook play.yml``` in your Dockerfile

Comment: I can, but I don't want. I want container to be clear. I don't understand clearly procedure now.

1. Create and run container.
2. Install to it some app.
3. Stop and create new image based no this container
4. Start new container based on new image
5. Install next app above
etc .... 

Can I do like this? What should be my first container? FROM ??

Comment: you can run the container I mean ```docker run -ti centos bash``` install somehow your application (using ansible for instance). exit container. Commit it and use as a base image for future usage (```FROM my_new_commited_img```)  OR you can create Dockerfile ```FROM centos``` and add many RUN command in order to install your application, for instance, ```RUN ansible-playbook play.yml``` - the 2nd approach is better cause such Dockerfile you can push to git repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t the standard way to create a Docker image and it isn’t what I’d do, but it will work.  Consider looking at a tool like Hashicorp’s [Packer](https://packer.io/) that can automate this sequence.

Ignoring the specific details of the tools, the important thing about the `docker build` sequence is that you have some file checked into source control that an automated process can use to build a Docker image.  An Ansible playbook coupled with a Packer JSON template would meet this same basic requirement.

The important thing here though is that there are some key differences between the Docker runtime environment and a bare-metal system or VM that you’d typically configure with Ansible: it’s unlikely you’ll be able to use your existing playbook unmodified.  For example, if your playbook tries to configure system daemons, install a systemd unit file, add ssh users, or other standard system administrative tasks, these generally aren’t relevant or useful in Docker.

I’d suggest making at least one attempt to package your application using a standard Dockerfile to actually understand the ecosystem.  Don’t expect to be able to use an Ansible playbook unmodified in a Docker environment; but if your organization has a lot of Ansible experience and you can easily separate “install the application” from “configure the server”, the path you’re suggesting is technically fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) in Docker, which might be a nice solution:

```
FROM ansible/centos7-ansible:stable as builder
COPY playbook.yaml .
RUN ansible-playbook playbook.yaml

FROM alpine:latest # Include whatever image you need for your application
# Add required setup for your app
COPY --from=builder . . # Copy files build in the ansible image, aka your app
CMD ["<command to run your app>"]
```

Hopefully the example is clear enough for you to create your Dockerfile